# Is there a single word verb for "make available"?

Tags: word-request

I've tried to consult various dictionaries as well as Google, but to no avail, so I hope someone here can see it in their heart to help me out.

I'm looking for a single word verb meaning 'to make available'. I obviously can't say "availablise", but is there something else I can use? I know I can paraphrase – it's not that – I just want to know whether there is a single word verb for this.

Examples:

> The efforts focus on modernising, improving and *availablising education

> We want to explain, discuss and *availablise old literature

As I said, I know I can rephrase, but I still want to know if there is a single word verb I could use here.

Comment: For education, how can you modernize it and improve it if you don't already have it?? And what does "make old literature available" really mean anyway? Again, how do you explain it and discuss it if you don't already have it??

Comment: @Lambie the people who want to make it available have it, and they want to make it available to others.

Comment: My previous questions are still unanswered. to make old literature available just is really weird, content-wise.

Comment: @Lambie Ok, I'll let my client know :)

Comment: There is a single word, Helen.  That word is **provide**, as Henning indicates.   If the single word that means *to make something available* is not an acceptable word to use for *to make something available* please update your question.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provide

Comment: @EllieK "**provide** old literature" has a slightly different meaning, in that it suggests old literature in general. What I'm after is a verb that indicates that we have a specific set of old books that we want to make available to the public. See what I mean? "I want to make this book available to the public" works, but "I want to provide this book to the public" doesn't, does it?

Comment: @Helen - I think I understand.  You are looking for a verb that can modify your noun.  In English verbs do not modify nouns but we can clarify the object of provide.  *We want to explain, discuss and provide **access to** some of the **old literature in our collection.***  Now we are not providing the books we are providing access to the books.

Comment: @EllieK I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "modify nouns" in this context (I guess verbs never modify nouns, regardless of language, or they wouldn't be verbs?), but apart from this, I totally buy your suggestion! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could for example

- provide something
- supply something
- furnish something

depending on the context. Within specialized contexts, there may be addional ways of putting it.

Comment: Thank you! I've added some examples now. I find that none of the verbs you suggest mean quite the same thing...

Comment: @Helen - I think *provide* is the word you seek.  The efforts focus on modernizing, improving, and **providing** education.  Why do you think it doesn't work?  Definition #1 is *make available for use* (i.e. availablise).

Comment: @EllieK See my comment above :)

Answer (score 0):

> **distribute**: ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distribute))
>
> to give something out to several people, or to spread or supply
> something:

or

> [**disseminate:**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disseminate)
>
> to spread or give out something, especially news, information, ideas,
> etc., to a lot of people:

Comment: Thank you! I feel these don't really express the same meaning either though. I guess I have my answer by now though: there isn't a single word verb for this meaning :)